# Getting all possible combinations of a List of KeyValue Pairs in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, data-structures, keyvaluepair

I have a key value pair like this:

`var accounts = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();`

and the contents of accounts looks like this:

```
{[4,10000]}
{[4,19000]}
{[4,11000]}
{[4,12000]}
{[4,13036]}
{[4,47100]}
{[5,19300]}
{[5,32900]}
{[5,95800]}
{[6,95800]}
```

How can I get **all possible combinations** of the key value pairs in `accounts` such that I have:

```
[{4,10000},{5,19300},{6,95800}],
[{4,10000},{5,32900},{6,95800}].....
```

The data structure containing the final result is not of much importance to me, I'm just interested in achieving this as efficiently as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a short search i found that you can do it using the [CartesianProduct Extension Method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) from [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(t => t.Key).CartesianProduct();
```

as it is doing:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
  this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```