# C# code to generate a combination results from a dataset

Tags: c#, logic

I have data set as below:

```
{A, 1},
{A, 2},
{B, 2},
{B, 3},
{C, 4},
{C, 5},
{D, 1},
{D, 3}
```

Looking to write a c# code to generate all the unique combinations for this dataset in such a way that each combination has A B C and D occurring once.

**Expected results:**

```
Combination 1 : {A, 1},{B, 2},{C, 4},{D, 1}
Combination 2:  {A, 2},{B, 2},{C, 4},{D, 1}
Combination 3 : {A, 2},{B, 3},{C, 4},{D, 1}
....
...
..
*so on..*
```

Comment: If you group those by the letter then you just want the Cartesian product of the resulting groups, and Eric Lippert has a nice blog post about how to do that https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/

Comment: Is there a question here? Please add the code that you have so far and the details about the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all possible combinations of a List of KeyValue Pairs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075173/getting-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-keyvalue-pairs-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that is based on Eric Lippert's [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

```
var input = new List<(char Letter, int Number)>
{
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 2),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 3),
    ('C', 4),
    ('C', 5),
    ('D', 1),
    ('D', 3), 
};

var output = input.GroupBy(x => x.Letter)
    .Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<(char, int)>(), 1),
        (acc, seq) =>
            from accseq in acc
            from item in seq
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item}));

            
foreach(var seq in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", seq));
}
```

Which produces

```
(A, 1);(B, 2);(C, 4);(D, 1)
(A, 1);(B, 2);(C, 4);(D, 3)
(A, 1);(B, 2);(C, 5);(D, 1)
(A, 1);(B, 2);(C, 5);(D, 3)
(A, 1);(B, 3);(C, 4);(D, 1)
(A, 1);(B, 3);(C, 4);(D, 3)
(A, 1);(B, 3);(C, 5);(D, 1)
(A, 1);(B, 3);(C, 5);(D, 3)
(A, 2);(B, 2);(C, 4);(D, 1)
(A, 2);(B, 2);(C, 4);(D, 3)
(A, 2);(B, 2);(C, 5);(D, 1)
(A, 2);(B, 2);(C, 5);(D, 3)
(A, 2);(B, 3);(C, 4);(D, 1)
(A, 2);(B, 3);(C, 4);(D, 3)
(A, 2);(B, 3);(C, 5);(D, 1)
(A, 2);(B, 3);(C, 5);(D, 3)
```